# Replace comma ',' with a value while converting xml to csv using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to convert a XML file to CSV file. The XML file has a address field which contains ',' comma, so after the conversion my result does not fall under the correct column so how do I replace ',' with space or some other value in my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Details>
    <EmpDetails>
        <Name>AAA</Name>
        <Age>51</Age> 
        <Sex>M</Sex>
        <Address>
            <AdderessLine1>25, SilverStreet</AdderessLine1>
            <AdderessLine2></AdderessLine2>               
        </Address>
        <JobLocation>India</JobLocation>
    </EmpDetails>
    <EmpDetails>
        <Name>BBB</Name>
        <Age>62</Age> 
        <Sex>M</Sex>
        <Address>
            <AdderessLine1>12, GoldStreet</AdderessLine1>
            <AdderessLine2></AdderessLine2>               
        </Address>
        <JobLocation>China</JobLocation>
    </EmpDetails>
<Details>
```

Above xml is just sample for to explain my problem.
**Following file is sample xsl file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"> Name, Age, Sex, Address
    <xsl:for-each select="//Details">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name,',',Age,',',Sex,',',Address,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image: expected output]
**My expected output:**

[image: My output]
**My output:**

Comment: it would be better to use `;` for separating fields in the csv. If you could process the csv before converting to xml, use that character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be to always put quote marks around the address field

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:text>Name, Age, Sex, Address&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="//EmpDetails">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name,',',Age,',',Sex,',&quot;',Address/AdderessLine1,'&quot;,&quot;',JobLocation,'&quot;&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If you only wanted to do this where the field has a comma in, you could use a template to add logic to check for commas

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:text>Name, Age, Sex, Address, JobLocation&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//EmpDetails">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name,',',Age,',',Sex)"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Address/AdderessLine1" />
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="JobLocation" />
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[contains(., ',')]">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the case when the field does not have a comma in, XSLT's built in templates apply, which will just output the text value of the element regardless.

Note your XML has the element name `AdderessLine1`. It probably should be `AddressLine1`